# Carrierwave config with fog/aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My application seems to be throwing an error on startup when using the fog/aws gem and the instructions in the carrierwave wiki.

I simply want to upload to Amazon S3.

The error being thrown is

```
 undefined method `fog_provider=' for CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:Class
```

Gemfile.rb

```
gem "fog"
gem "fog-aws"
gem "carrierwave"
```

initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     'KEYID',
    aws_secret_access_key: 'SECRETID',
    region:                'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket-name'
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .................

Your **initializers/carrierwave.rb** look like this.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',                        # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

**In your uploader, set the storage to :fog**

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
end
```

Comment: I shared my initializer above and it looks the same. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to remove `config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'` line.

Comment: If your gem version v0.10.0 then refer this link https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/tree/v0.10.0

Comment: I updated my code please check if this works for you.

Comment: you can skip optional parameters.

Comment: [`config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'`](https://gist.github.com/darrenboyd/feb2bc38f46a88e44b8d#gistcomment-2741302)

Answer (score 0):

`CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:Class#fog_provider=` is not released yet. It is only available on the CarrierWave `master` branch.

**Solution 1 (Use master):**
Change your `Gemfile` entry to

```
gem "carrierwave", git: "git@github.com:carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git"
```

But this is not recommended since it is not as stable as a release version.

---

**Solution 2 (Check 0.10 documentation):**

In `0.10` you set the `:provider` using `fog_credentials=`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',                        # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

View documentation for [v0.10 here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/tree/v0.10.0).

Comment: My config looks the same as yours above. I am setting the provider key. I agree, I would rather not use master.